# what exactly does setting the AIR namespace do?

Tags: flash, air

so when setting the AIR namespace in the application-descriptor of an AIR application, it basically tells which is the minimum AIR runtime the app will be compatible with, right?

but does it do anything more than disallowing the installation if a lower runtime version is installed?

For example, if AIR runtime 3.0 is installed, may an application perform in way different if the namespace was set either to 2.0 or to 3.0 in the application descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

The AIR namespace does three things:

- Distinguishes the SDK of AIR from the other possible environments (Flex) for the compiler
- Imports AIR specific packages into the runtime environment
- Deprecates AIR packages that have been deprecated based on the version number, and introduces new packages based on the version number

For example:

> You must update your application descriptor file to the 16 namespace in order to access the new AIR 16 APIs and behavior. If your application does not require the new AIR 16 APIs and behavior, you are not required to update the namespace. However, we recommend all users start using the AIR 16 namespace even if you are not yet taking advantage of the new 16 capabilities. To update the namespace, change the xmlns attribute in your application descriptor to: `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0">`

**References**

- [Release Notes | Flash Player® 16 AIR® 16](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_16_air_16_release_notes.html)
- [Relationship of Adobe AIR SDK and Flex SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554447/1113772)
- [Looking for Old Flex SDKs?](http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2012/05/looking-for-old-flex-sdks.html)
- [Developing for Mobile Devices with the Adobe Flash Platform](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/mobile-development-flash-platform.html)